# Dash not opening if there are no windows open

Tags: unity-dash, settings

I've had Budgie installed for testing purposes. After removing it everything seems to be fine, except that the dash doesn't open when i press the super key, as long as there are no windows open. If i have any window like firefox or ccsm open, it works just fine.

Hope you can help me
Spark

Answer (score 0):

ok got a fix. Some people had this issue after (un)installing gnome. activating desktop-icons in the gnome-tweak-tool did the trick.